# Getting list of items in mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

I currently have a list of things to update in the given mysqli query:

```
$insert = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE `tbl_perms` SET
 `1` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_1']) . "',    
 `2` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_2']) . "',    
 `3` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_3']) . "',    
 `4` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_4']) . "',    
 `5` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_5']) . "', 
 `6` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_6']) . "',
 `7` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_7']) . "',
 `8` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_8']) . "',
 `9` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_9']) . "',
`10` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_10']) . "'
 WHERE `userid` = '$id' ")or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

How would I rewrite this so that I don't have to manually code the sql in so that when "permissions" are added, this automatically generates the sql needed to do the sql query?

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you know when a permission gets added? When it's available in POST? And also: are there max. 10 permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$updaters = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    if (isset($_POST['permsA_'.$i]))
        $updaters[] = '`'.$i.'` = \''.mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['permsA_'.$i]).'\'';
}

$insert = mysqli_query($db,'UPDATE `tbl_perms` SET '.implode(',', $updaters).
    'WHERE `userid` = '.$id)or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
  if (preg_match('/^permsA/',$key)) {
    list($tmp,$num)=explode('_',$key);
    $perms[]="`$num` = " . (int)$value; //or some other method of sanitizing the $value
  }
}

$sql="UPDATE tbl_perms SET " . implode(','$perms) . "WHERE userid = '$id'" ;
```

Comment: Just a minor deal: `strpos($key, 'permsA')===0` would be a smidge faster than the preg_match. :) Also... don't forget to validate/sanitize `$num` (that's an injection hole at the moment)

Comment: I like your `foreach` loop as it's more abstract, but why do you compare with `preg_match`? Won't comparing against a substring be faster?

Comment: @JoostK: preg_match is slower, yes. but I remember its syntax better and I didn't want to stop to look up the other. :$

Answer (score 3):

What the others said, except if possible I'd do it a bit differently - rather than having to use a $i to control the loop, I'd rename the form so that the fields were called something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="permsA[1]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="permsA[2]">
```

etc etc.

You'd then get a post array you could reference like this like this:

```
$_POST['permsA'][1];
$_POST['permsA'][2];
```

Advantage of this is that you can do:

```
$bits = array();
foreach ($_POST['permsA'] as $key=>$value) {
  $bits[] = $key . " = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value) . "'";
}

$sql = "UPDATE permissions SET " . implode(', ', $bits) . " WHERE userid = '$id' ") 
 or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

And the advantage of doing that is that you won't one day get a random bug when you add more permissions to the system and go past the max you are using for $1 :)

Appreciate you may not be able to change the form though, or may not ever add more permissions, in which case this solution is no better.

Answer (score 0):

Just a draft:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `tbl_perms` SET ";
for ($i = 1; $i < 100; i++) {
  if (isset($_POST['permsA_' . $i])) {
    if ($i > 1) $sql .= ",";
    $sql .= "`$i` ='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['permsA_1']) . "'";
  }
}
$sql .= " WHERE `userid` = '$id'";
```

Please note that the 100 is just an arbitrary number

Comment: That's wrong. You cannot use the + operator like this in PHP.

Comment: he probably meant .= instead of +=